# Abbreviation in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, abbreviation

Treat abbreviation like Sta. equals to Santa, or Ma. equals to Maria or Ma.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 A WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE A.Name LIKE '%ma%'
```

This query is for Maria, but the problem is it also included a name contains `marie`

Case 1: User input `ma` the result would be `maria`, `ma`, and `ma.` and vice versa.

Case 2: User Inputs `Maria` the outputs would be `Ma. Teresa` or `Maria Teresa` or `Ma Teresa` and same goes on `sta` scenario.

Case 3: User input `sta` the result would be `santa`, `sta.` and `sta` and vice versa.

Case 4: User input normal name (Jose) without abbreviation the result would be like `Jose`

Any idea on this problem? or what is the best approach for this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I edited my question, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is function to check if the search contains `ma`, `ma.`....

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[StringContains]
(
-- Add the parameters for the function here
@String1 VARCHAR(MAX),
@String2 VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
-- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE @Result BIT = 0

DECLARE @IsContain INT = 0

DECLARE @Equivalents TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Text1 VARCHAR(50),
    Text2 VARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO @Equivalents (Text1, Text2)
VALUES ('ma. ','maria'),
('ma. ','ma '),
('ma ','maria'),
('sta. ','santa'),
('sta. ','sta '),
('sta ','santa')

DECLARE @ID INT = 1
DECLARE @TOTAL INT = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @Equivalents)
WHILE @ID <= @TOTAL
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        @Temp1 VARCHAR(MAX) = @String1,
        @Temp2 VARCHAR(MAX) = @String2,
        @Text1 VARCHAR(50),
        @Text2 VARCHAR(50)
    SELECT TOP 1
        @Text1 = Text1,
        @Text2 = Text2
    FROM @Equivalents
    WHERE ID = @ID

    IF @Temp1 LIKE '%'+@Text1+'%' AND @Temp2 LIKE '%'+@Text2+'%'
    BEGIN
        SET @String2 = REPLACE(@Temp2,@Text2,@Text1)
    END
    ELSE IF @Temp1 LIKE '%'+@Text2+'%' AND @Temp2 LIKE '%'+@Text1+'%'
    BEGIN
        SET @String2 = REPLACE(@Temp2,@Text1,@Text2)
    END

    IF @String1 LIKE '%'+@String2+'%'
    BEGIN
        SET @IsContain += 1
    END

    SET @ID += 1
END

SET @Result = (CASE WHEN @IsContain > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
RETURN @Result
END
```

And this is the query.

```
DECLARE @Text VARCHAR(MAX) = 'maria'
SELECT TOP 100 FullName,* FROM dbo.Table1 WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE dbo.StringContains(FullName,@Text) = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to have a list of all abbreviations and what they correspond to.

Essentially, build a separate table that would expand abbreviation into full name.

Table `Abbrevs` with columns `Abbrev, Name`.

For your example it will contain these rows:

```
Abbrev Name
ma     Maria
ma     Ma.
ma.    Maria
ma.    Ma
sta    Santa
sta    Sta.
sta.   Santa
sta.   sta
```

Then look for the string that user provided plus all possible synonyms of this name. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @ParamInput nvarchar(255);
SET @ParamInput = 'ma';

SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE
    YourTable.Name = @ParamInput
    OR YourTable.Name IN
    (
        SELECT Abbrevs.Name
        FROM Abbrevs
        WHERE Abbrevs.Abbrev = @ParamInput
    )
;
```

You may let user define and edit the `Abbrevs` table.

---

If both user input and the table may have abbreviations, and you need to use `LIKE`, not a simple `=` for searching, then I'd do something like the following.

There will still be a separate table that expands abbreviations (or, rather a list of possible abbreviations of a specific name):

```
Abbrev Name
ma     Maria
ma.    Maria
sta    Santa
sta.   Santa
```

In addition to that I would have a function that normalizes the given name. The function would search for possible abbreviations in the given name and expand them.

For example, given `Ma. Teresa`, the function will return `Maria Teresa` using the `Abbrevs` table.

Your main table has a field `Name` with original name that can have abbreviations. I'll add another (computed or persisted) column `NormalizedName`, which would be populated by this function. In practice I made such column as a normal persisted column and wrote a trigger that updated its value when the main `Name` column changes. One step of normalization was to bring all strings to upper case. You may build some other rules into it, like discarding all dots, commas, dashes and other such symbols, replacing double spaces with single space, etc.

You show to the user only original `Name` values.

When a user provides a name to search for, I normalize the given name using the same function and search for normalized value in the `NormalizedName` column with a simple

```
WHERE NormalizedName LIKE '%'+@ParamNormalizedName+'%'
```

Comment: If the user Inputs `Maria` the outputs would be `Ma. Teresa` or `Maria Teresa` or `Ma Teresa`? Is there LIKE IN function?

Comment: @JAlc, I expanded the answer and added idea that I used - normalizing names.

Comment: Thank you for your idea!

Comment: Im stack on creating a normalized function for name. This is what I've done so far. Any idea what i am missing? https://pastebin.com/YJQA71gE

Comment: @JAlc, you'd better ask another question with specific problem that you have. You don't need to reinvent a function that [splits a string into a table](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings).

Comment: thanks. I already have a solution to my problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have a period for the abbreviation, so this might do what you want:

```
WHERE ' ' + A.Name + ' ' LIKE '% Ma. %'
```